# Bootstrap 4 popover arrow outline

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, pseudo-element

I have found 100 different answers to this question but none seem to work. I am trying to get rid of the outline on the Bootstrap 4 popover arrow. I have tried every pseudo target I can think of. I am using a bottom popover. Any help is super appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following. Atleast it is working on their site.

```
.popover .arrow::before {
   border-bottom-color: white; /* might need to add !important */
}
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```css
.popover .arrow::before {
   border-bottom-color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on bottom
</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Yes! Its actually a combination of these two answers...

.bs-popover-auto[x-placement^=bottom] .arrow::before, .bs-popover-bottom .arrow::before {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: white; 
}

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
.popover .arrow:before {
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Or if you use bootstrap variables:

```
$popover-arrow-outer-color: transparent;
```